# Django test to check for pending migrations

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-migrations

Django has a [`--check` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48442671) that let's you check if migrations need to be created for your project. This is relatively easy to add in CI, but that won't perform the check on developer computers.

I want to add this check as a unit test in my Django project, so that it is covered when developers run our test suite.

What is a good way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following unittest:

```
from io import StringIO

def test_for_missing_migrations():
    output = StringIO()
    call_command("makemigrations", no_input=True, dry_run=True, stdout=output)
    assert output.getvalue().strip() == "No changes detected", (
        "There are missing migrations:\n %s" % output.getvalue()
    )
```

It checks whether the result of python manage.py makemigrations returns a "No changes detected", which means there are no migrations that need to be created.

Comment: What is StringIO class ? Where does it come from ?

Comment: @lbris StringIO comes from: `from io import StringIO`. The io module provides the Python interfaces to stream handling.

Comment: Maybe you should update your answer to include this import statement, for the sake of clarity. Thanks for your answer.